# HTML Image Map Not Displaying Tooltips

Tags: html, tooltip, imagemap

My image displays fine on the webpage. However, only the first area title shows in a tooltip when hovering over any part of the image. The other areas will not show. Here is the html I have.

```html
<html>

<map name="eyfsplayarea">
  <area shape="circle" coords="930,300,70" alt="The Mud Kitchen and Digging Zone" title="The Mud Kitchen and Digging Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="790,200,50" alt="The Niagara Channelling System, Water Table and Water Wall" title="The Niagara Channelling System, Water Table and Water Wall">
  <area shape="circle" coords="890,180,20" alt="The Sand Tray" title="The Sand Tray">
  <area shape="rect" coords="323,150,850,100" alt="A Sheltered Covered Area Linked to the Building" title="A Sheltered Covered Area Linked to the Building">
  <area shape="circle" coords="600,200,40" alt="A Roadway, Numeracy and Literacy Zone" title="A Roadway, Numeracy and Literacy Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="400,300,70" alt="Physical Development and Role Play Zone" title="Physical Development and Role Play Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="690,300,90" alt="Physical Development and Role Play Zone" title="Physical Development and Role Play Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="246,612,104" alt="The Storytellers Chair, Phonics and Mark Making Zone" title="The Storytellers Chair, Phonics and Mark Making Zone">
  <area shape="circle" coords="244,190,54" alt="Role Play House with Chalkboard" title="Role Play House with Chalkboard">
  <area shape="circle" coords="593,615,105" alt="Den Posts" title="Den Posts">
  <area shape="circle" coords="1360,619,93" alt="The Language Lounge" title="The Language Lounge">
</map>

<img src="/EYFS-Outdoor-Play-and-Learning2.jpg" width="1621" height="725" alt="EYFS Play and Learning" usemap="#eyfsplayarea">

</html>
```

Comment: your coordinates are literally impossible given your source image.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Good spot, many thanks. I have amended this with the correct size image but that wasn't the only issue, I am experiencing the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please update your post with a corrected size, as it stands your html is still using coords which can't exist

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Okay, all updated now!

Comment: Your cirlcles and rectangles are wrong. circles have `x,y,radius` where as rectangles have `x1,y1,x2,y2`

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche I have changed my circles to just x,y but now I am not even seeing a single tooltip. Could you tell me how I should be taking the coords exactly for the circles? The tutorials I've looked at say the x,y of the centre

Comment: You've not updated your code, it's impossible to tell what you've done

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche It is now updated. The only change is the x2 and y2 were removed as you suggested.

Comment: I didn't suggest that at all, I stated that `x,y,radius` is required.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Okay, not to worry. Based on where I am with my code is there anything you can see that jumps out as a problem?

Comment: the radius of each circle is almost as big as your whole image. You also have a rectangle with 3 arguments! `459,147,1217147`

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Okay I have got it all working correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was that `circle` areas in image maps have three values, the x position, the y position and the [radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius) of the circle. Prior to editing they had the same number of parameters as the rectangles, and later their radius value was larger than the source image.